# Python function to return a new list without modifying the input list

Tags: python, list, copy

Folks,

I would like to have a function that takes a list as input, return another list which is a modification of the input, but I don't want to change the original list. Would the following code be the best I can do?

Also, in order to avoid mistakes, would it be better if I pass tuple(a) into the function modify(a) function and turn the tuple into list inside the modify(a) function?

Thanks very much for your reply.

```
def modify(a):
    b = a[:]
    # some changes on b here
    ......
    return b
```

Comment: Are you always working with two-element lists that you're reversing?  `a = b[::-1]`.  I don't see anything that indicates which indices you're intending to swap.

Comment: Could you be more elaborate as to what you need? How long will the lists be, what kind of swapping pattern do you want to use, do you want a user to be able to influence the swapping. Having this kind of info greatly helps us in helping you.

Comment: "some changes on b here" is useless information. Ask a specific question if you want a specific answer. Otherwise just fill in the blanks yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're code looks perfectly reasonable to me, you could replace `b = a[:]` with `b = list(a)` to make your code more general. Also there is no reason to use `tuple(a)`. If you want to go that route, you could let `modify` work in-place and call it like this `b = modify(a[:])`.

Answer (score 5):

If your list contains any sublists, dictionaries or other "mutable" elements, and your algorithm might make changes to them, then the shallow list copy that `oldlist[::-1]` gives you is not enough. Use `deepcopy` from the module `copy` to make a completely separate copy of your input.

```
from copy import deepcopy
newlist = deepcopy(oldlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why that's not satisfactory:

- You're copying the list so no worries about mangling it inadvertently
- Tuple unpacking is the most efficient way to swap two variables like that

Keep it that way, imo.

Answer (score 0):

This would only do for a list of len 2.

It doesnt really matter if you send a tuple but it totally depends on you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> def swap(l):
...   return l[::-1]
... 
>>> my_list = [1,2,3]
>>> swap(my_list)
[3, 2, 1]
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3]
```

Doesn't matter if it's a list or a tuple, it's swapped anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Tidying up your code without going so far as to use `a = b[::-1]`:

```
def swapped(b):
    assert len(b) == 2
    return [b[1], b[0]]
```

Choice of function name: `swapped` is to `swap` as `sorted` is to `sort` ... it indicates that the arg is NOT being mutated.

This can be generalised very easily:

```
def gather(sequence, indices):
    return [sequence[i] for i in indices]
```